# How to use the access_token to get contents of my App

Tags: java, json, podio

I need to access my podio app using access_token instead of being using username and password. The code i tried using username and password and its working finr for me. 
   I'm using

```
 ResourceFactory resourceFactory = new ResourceFactory(
       new OAuthClientCredentials("usedClientId","usedClientSecret"),
       new OAuthUsernameCredentials("abc@ggtd.com","Test123"));
   APIFactory apiFactory = new APIFactory(resourceFactory);
   ItemAPI itemAPI = apiFactory.getAPI(ItemAPI.class);
```

But i need to use accesstoken so that i may not be dependent on username and password for accessing app. For this i tried using

```
URL url = new URL("https://podio.com/oauth/token?granttype=app&appid=88069&apptoken=6a83845c6656ff4678a5eec668a10aa3e7&clientid=usedClientId-79unji&redirecturi=https://podio.com/abcd/workappname/apps/usedClient&client_secret=jIfs6qWsQJJ99eDDds1RMhmbKywAhsMtTYLFW8GVeFmmeAiCYOOdzDyc3yqdHBT");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

and i'm getting the response in the form of JSON like

```
{
accesstoken: "ae566736ffdb414ab23320c9d169d8a"
tokentype: "bearer"
ref: {
type: "app"
id: 88069
}-
expiresin: 98800
refreshtoken: "96bbfb0dd9e74ac6ad456f44896c4d3e"
}
```

which is 200 Response.
I took help of using https://github.com/podio/podio-java/tree/master/src/main/java/com/podio but no use.
Also refer https://developers.podio.com/authentication where also no help .
Now , How can i use this access_token in my java code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, NEVER post application id and secrets on such a websites.

You can use any JSON-parsing library to get this information, for example, the simplest example with GSON would be following:

```
public class AuthInfo {
    private String accesstoken, tokentype, ...

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accesstoken;
    }
}

// ...

Gson gson = new Gson();
String accessToken = gson.fromJson(response, AuthInfo.class).getAccessToken();
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not my real id or secrets .

Comment: If you check https://github.com/podio/podio-java/tree/master/src/main/java/com/podio then there ResourseFactory Class where only two constructors are defined which i need to use , but in each constructor OAuthUsernameCredentials has been added which requires username and password. So my question is how can use only access_token to retrieve the app imformation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried OAuthRefreshTokenCredentials ?

You should be able to use OAuthRefreshTokenCredentials which implements OAuthUserCredentials and let you use the refresh_token instead of the user_name / password (required in OAuthUsernameCredentials).

https://github.com/podio/podio-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/podio/oauth/OAuthRefreshTokenCredentials.java